# Use localized strings in storyboard

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

I'm pretty new to iOS development and I was asking my self if it is possible to use localized strings from my "Localizable.strings" file directly into the storyboard.
For example in Android you can do it from the XML file like this:

```
android:text="@string/notConnected"
```

I understood that you can make a localized version of the storyboard, but having different strings files and different storyboards looks pretty ugly to me.

So is it possible to have only strings files and use what I need into the storyboard? Preferably without setting it from code?

EDIT:
This is practically what I want to do:
[image: referencing string in storyboard]

So is this possible? Is there a legit way to call a string from there like in Android?

Comment: There are multiple WWDC videos across many years that cover Localisation and Internationalisation. Which ones have you watched? Apple also provide an `Internationalization and Localization Guide` which covers this topic; what problem are you having when you follow the documentation (please be specific): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html

Comment: Please see my edit, it seems that I haven't been clear enough

Comment: Did you read the documentation that I linked? What you are talking about is `Base Internationalization`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your requirement it's not possible but

You don't need different storyboards for localization

Suppose you want to localize a label string.

1. Draw and outlet and change text using

mylabel.text = nsLocalizedString("THIS_IS_MY_STRING",nil);

Of course in your localization file there will be a line.You must have different files for different language.Suppose you have a file for english and there must be a line.

"THIS_IS_MY_STRING" = "This is my string";

When you compile your app, that function will use mapping to localize your app.

Edit:

If you want detail information please have a look at these tutorials
[internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)

and [ios-localization-tutorial](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881)

There are some online script(e.g localize.py) which will help you to automatically search all of your code and find out nslocalizedString function and make lines in your localizableString files. like this.

"THIS_IS_MY_STRING" = "THIS_IS_MY_STRING"

and later on you just have to write actual string there. :)

Comment: I meant that if I have a static text on my label Xcode creates a specific file for storyboard localization, but my question was about using the strings in my localization file without writing from code where to use it, but directly into the storyboard editor

Comment: Please see my edit to understand what I really asked, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Well I'm perplessed about it being better but I'll document myself better, and if you edit your answer to also say that is not possible I'm gonna accept it, thank you for your time and patience

Answer (score 29):

I think being able to localise `String`s in the storyboard is of significant advantage. I don't agree with @elk_cloner that hooking up `IBOutlet`s for every `UILabel` is the way forward.

One way of getting it to work is using an @IBInspectable property on a `UILabel` subclass:

```
class LocalisableLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var localisedKey: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let key = localisedKey else { return }
            text = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
        }
    }

}
```

In the storyboard set the custom class:

[image]

In the attributes inspector the localisedKey field will appear and you can just add your key here.

[image]

That's it!

**EDIT:**

You can localise `UIButton`s the same way, BUT if the text in the storyboard's title field differs from the localised String (which it will in other languages) the setting of the title will animate.

To fix this, put the setTitle in a `performWithoutAnimation` block:

```
class LocalisableButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var localisedKey: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let key = localisedKey else { return }
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                setTitle(key.localized, for: .normal)
                layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any way that Xcode will render the string correctly in the storyboard?

Comment: @Niklas I don't think that's possible no.

Comment: @Niklas sure, just use @IBDesignable in subclasses.
```@IBDesignable
class DesignableButton: UIButton {

}
```
where UIButton has setter with ```set(value) { text = NSLocalizedString(value!, comment: "") }```

Comment: @SevenDays Niklas was asking about whether the localised text itself can be rendered in the storyboard.

Comment: @Leon yes, and I provided the solution on how to render localised text in the storyboard. It is done by using IBDesignable specifier in a subclass

Comment: @SevenDays Oh I see! Could you give me a full example as I'm not quite sure what you mean with the setter. I'm guessing what people want is the ability to put the localisedKey in the storyboard and it automatically renders the translated text, is that what you're suggesting can be done?

Answer (score 19):

In addition to [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50106068/1665966), you can get rid of the need for an explicit subclass by using an extension:

```
extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var localizableText: String? {
        get { return text }
        set(value) { text = NSLocalizedString(value!, comment: "") }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this [post](https://medium.com/@mario.negro.martin/easy-xib-and-storyboard-localization-b2794c69c9db) you can find a detailed explanation of this approach, together with an [example](https://github.com/emenegro/xib-localization) for a few widgets.

Comment: Very nice and neat.

Answer (score 3):

Make a button class and set **@IBInspectable** attribute to the button class

```
    class Button: UIButton {                 

      @IBInspectable public var referenceText: String = "" {
          didSet {
              self.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(referenceText, comment: ""), for: .normal)
          }
      }
}
```

Then in the storyboard you can set referenceText[image]

The button text will be "Sign In"

Comment: A great solution works perfectly! I adapted it for a UILabel and all my different views with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to localize the storyboard and simply change the values for labels and buttons directly on the `.string` file.

First select the storyboard, and click on localize:

[image]

Then you'll be able to select the languages you want.

[image]

This way you'll be able to continue developing on your language of choice and simply edit the `.string` file that is generated